# How to use 1 form to insert into multiple tables using Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, crud

I have a form page for storing recording data of a specific artist. Most data belongs to the recording table but some data should be stored in related tables. My main concern right now is the Genre table. In the genre table I have the Name column. My idea of the ideal process after the form has been submitted is something like:

1. Check if the genre name already exists
2. If not: store the name and use its id as a fk
3. If yes: fetch genre id and use it as a fk

What I am working on is the store method in the Recording controller. Currently I am working with
$recording_date, $release_date and $lyrics from the recording table.

DISCLAIMER:
I will not show you much of what I've tried because cannot show you all the ways I've tried and it's also useless cause the problem isn't that I don't understand why it isn't working. I just can't find any way at all to do it properly with Eloquent that includes the same constraints and with a 1-to-many relation. Most people would suggest me to do it in separate forms.

Also I'm aware of that I'm not handling the validation right now.
Anyway, any ideas or suggestions where I can find information of similar cases applicable on mine would help.

```
<!--Form snippet-->
<div class="form-group">
    <div class="input-group">
        <input type="text" name="genre" class="form-control" placeholder="Genre" autocomplete="off">
    </div>
</div>
```

The following was the latest piece of code I tried. The obvious reason why it doesn't work is that it doesn't deal with the foreign key.

```
//Recording controller
public function store(Request $request)
    {
        $genre = new Genre();
        $genre->name = $request->input('genre');

        $recording = new Recording();
        $recording->genre_id = $genre->id;
        $recording->recording_date = $request->input('recording_date');
        $recording->release_date = $request->input('release_date');
        $recording->lyrics = $request->input('lyrics');
        $recording->save();
    }
```

```
//Recording table
public function up()
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('recordings', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->bigIncrements('id');
            $table->unsignedInteger('genre_id')->nullable();
            $table->string('recording_date')->nullable();
            $table->string('release_date')->nullable();
            $table->text('lyrics')->nullable();
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }
```

```
//Genres table
 public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('genres', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->bigIncrements('id');
            $table->string('name')->unique()->nullable();
            $table->string('subgenre')->nullable();
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }
```

```
//Recording model
class Recording extends Model
{
    protected $guarded = [];

    public function genre() {
        return $this->belongsTo(Genre::class);
    }
}
```

```
//Genre model
class Genre extends Model
{
    protected $guarded = [];

    public function recordings() {
        return $this->hasMany(Recording::class);
    }
}
```

Comment: You never call `$genre->save()`, so `$genre->id` is `null`, and `$recording->genre_id = $genre->id;` won't work. Also, I think you posted the wrong code for your `Recordings` migration.

Comment: @TimLewis Oh, yes I did post the wrong code. I'm so sorry. Thanks for pointing it out. I will try to edit it.

Answer (score 0):

In order to save onto relationship tables you have to do:

```
$recording->genre()->create('your data array here')
```

you can read more about it [here](https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/eloquent-relationships#the-create-method).

Now if you want to check it out if that $recording has an genre you could first use exists() like:

```
$recording->genre()->exists()
```

Another option would be to use the methods firstOrCreate, firstOrNew, you can read more about them [here](https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/eloquent#other-creation-methods).

Answer (score 0):

Please try this

```
....

$genre->save();

$genre->recordings()->create([
  "recording_date"=>$request->input('recording_date'),
  "release_date"=>$request->input('release_date'),
  "lyrics"=>$request->input('lyrics')
]);
```